# Move div element from one parent div to another

Tags: javascript, jquery

So let's assume that I have a set of nested divs:

```
<div id="likelyToBeCalled">
    <div id="likelyOddHeader" class="row">
        <div id="likelyOddA" class="left" name="test1">Test1</div>
        <div id="LikelyOddB" class="middle"><img src="image002.png"/></div>
        <div id="timeZone" class="right">West</div>
    </div>
```

and further down the page:

```
<div id="unlikelyToBeCalled">
    <div id="likelyOddHeader" class="row">
        <div id="likelyOddA" class="left">Test2</div>
        <div id="LikelyOddB" class="middle"><img src="image002.png"/></div>
        <div id="timeZone" class="right">West</div>
    </div>
```

How would I move Test1 to "unlikelyToBeCalled".  I've been trying this with a form / submit button just for kicks, here's the code for that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function doSubmit() {
        document.getElementById('unlikelyToBeCalled').appendChild(
            document.getElementsByTagName('Test1')
        );
    }
</script>
<br /><br /><br />
<form method="POST" action="file:///C:/wamp/www/index.html" id="submitform" name="submitform">
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Move divs" onClick="doSubmit()"  />
</form>
```

Or something to that effect.  Any help would rock

Comment: You tagged [tag:jquery] but your code is in pure javascript, how do you want answer?

Comment: `action="file:///C:/wamp/www/index.html"` --- this looks wrong

Comment: Here are a couple of other StackOverflow answers: [Jquery]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279957/how-to-move-an-element-into-another-element, [Pure JS]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3415480/moving-a-div-element-to-bottom-of-parent-as-last-child

Comment: Also, your example html contains duplicate ID's.

Answer (score 9):

Use `.appendTo()`

```
$('#likelyOddA').appendTo('#unlikelyToBeCalled')
```

Comment: You don't have to detach it, `appendTo` will automagically remove it from it's previous location.

Comment: do not forget the prepentTo if you want to insert it in the beginning instead of end

Answer (score 5):

If I understand what you want:

```
$('div[name=test1]').appendTo('#unlikelyToBeCalled');
```

`getElementsByTagName('Test1')` will not get element with `name="Test1"`, it is supposed to, for example, get all `div`s (with code `getElementsByTagName('div')` of course). Next, you have used `#likelyOddHeader` and other `id`s twice, but `id` must be unique.