# Problem while moveing an element to the bottom of its parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I *literally* move an element to the bottom of its parent? There were [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3415480/moving-a-div-element-to-bottom-of-parent-as-last-child) [similar](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-move-an-element-to-end-of-it-s-parent) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18427255/jquery-move-element-to-last-child-position), but my element has a scroll bar, and using the methods of the questions I linked (like using `appendTo`) makes my element scroll to the top. How can I prevent this or just really *move* it to the bottom?

Comment: Does my answer work for you?

Comment: Almost . . . . .

Comment: What's the issue?

Answer (score 1):

After appending, you can manually set the `scrollTop` to scroll to the bottom as well.

```
scrollingDiv.scrollTop = scrollingDiv.scrollHeight;
```